# How to I retrieve default checkbox values using Form API?

Tags: forms

**How do I retrieve saved checkbox values from a field using the FormAPI?**

The form/node saves successfully, and when I look in the DB, the data was successively saved in the 'field_data_field_test' table, but I can't figure out how to pull that back out and apply the 'checked' status using #default_value.

`$form['field_test']['und']['#default_value'] = $How_Can_I_Get_This_Data_From_DB`

Is there a function I can use to retrieve checked values for a given field within a given node?  I'm trying to avoid direct queries. :)

Edit:

Ended up using

```
function _get_review_site_defaults() {
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    global $user;
    $result = $query
            ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
            ->entityCondition('bundle', 'field_test', '=')
            ->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid, '=')
            ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
            ->execute();
    if (count($result) == 0) {
        $defaults = array(1);
    } else {
        $entities = entity_load('node', array_keys($result['node']));
        foreach ($entities as $key => $value) {
            if ($value->field_default_field_test[$value->language][0]['value'] == 'Yes') {
                $defaults[] = $value->nid;
            }
        }
    }
    return $defaults;
}
```

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7??

Comment: Drupal Seven (7)

Comment: if you solve your own answer, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you save it, it saves the value of the checkbox as #value (not #default_value).

When defining the field settings: 
(pulled from D7 cck_table.module)

```
  $form['css_class'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('CSS Class'),
    '#description' => t('Specify a class to be added to the table element.'),
    **'#default_value' => isset($field['css_class']) ? $field['css_class'] : '',**
  );
```

**Revised**:

More likely you would want to do this:

If you want to grab the default values, you can call `field_info_field($field_name

> Returns data about an individual field, given a field name.